# AWS EBS io1 IOPS pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

My AWS EC2 application consistently requires about 3000 IOPS, but only about 100 GB disk space. Comparing the prices between `gp2` and `io1` it looks like (from https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/ for Ohio):

- `gp2`: 1000GB disk would cost $100/month ($0.10/GB-month * 1000GB). There would be 90% wasted disk space, but I'd get my 3000 IOPS sustained.
- `io1`: 100GB disk + 3000 IOPS would cost $207/month (0.065/IOPS-month * 3000IOPS + 0.125/GB-month * 100GB).

Am I doing the math right? Is it really 2x as expensive to get a smaller disk with the same IOPS on `io1`? It seems like there would never be a reason to use `io1` and instead just get enough `gp2` disk space to get the IOPS for free. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've done the maths correctly, I confirmed with the [AWS Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator).

Yes, provisioned IOPS is quite a bit more expensive than gp2. Using a large gp2 volume is a standard way to save money. You get a slightly better guarantee of performance with IO1 - 99.9% instead of 99%.

You might also test that you do get all the IOPS you need using GP2. In theory you should, but maybe only using a fraction of the disk it wouldn't give you the full throughput. You should test that.

[This article](https://www.apptio.com/emerge/it-possible-use-ebs-gp2-instead-io1-achieve-same-performance-and-save-50/) is a useful reference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answer, Tim! I hadn't seen the AWS Calculator before, really helpful.